# Common Code Distribution Using NuGet Packages?

Tags: .net, architecture, nuget, projects-and-solutions

Given a distributed enterprise-scale system design and a self-hosted NuGet Repository Server, does anyone think that it's a good idea to use NuGet packages as a means for distributing compiled dll's for the layers of the system?

The system will be architected to follow strict onion architecture principles and design...

PROS:
- NuGet versioning is awesome.
- integrated with a CI server (TeamCity in my case), this seems like it could be quite an elegant solution.
- easy to deploy and for other team members to use.
- updates are easy to do (and with TeamCity, even easier)
- any others??

CONS:
- debugging and jumping into code when troubleshooting (though NuGet can include debug symbols just haven't figured out how to do this in teamcity.)
- others??

Thanks for the feedback!

RELATED: [Git submodules vs Nuget packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411929/git-submodules-vs-nuget-packages)

Comment: For example, when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 site, several nuget packages that are framework components are installed, like the System.Web.Optimization library. I was looking to do the same sorta thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NuGet packages for any dependency outside of your current system. The more it is stable, the easier it is.

Regarding Symbols, check this link to learn how to set up your own SymbolSource server on-premise http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step. In TeamCity, you just need to make sure the -Symbols flag is passed on to the NuGet.exe command line.