# How to temporarily replace a NuGet reference with a local build

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm working on a C# project using Visual Studio 2015, with NuGet for package management. For one reference, I'd like to temporarily use a local build while I'm iterating on a fix, rather than the released version. What's the best way to accomplish this?

If I were using an SVN external, I'd drop the new locally built copies into the external reference's folder, and be set. Other package management software (like CocoaPods) would allow me to point to a local directory to resolve the reference. With NuGet, it doesn't look like there's any mechanism for this.

When I try dropping my new DLL over the package reference inside the `packages` folder, I get inconsistent behavior in Visual Studio. My build will fail with hundreds of errors, most of which go away from the Error List quickly. I'm ultimately left with a warning telling me it could not resolve the reference to the assembly I'm trying to replace (though the properties of the reference do indicate it's finding my new version).

Comment: I'm trying to test out unfinished library code in my app that consumes it. Since it's unfinished, I'm not yet ready to commit and publish my changes.

Comment: You know, that following SemVer and having a local repository does partially solve your problem ... What's the problem with committing beta-packages? Though, I do understand the additional overhead (which I am facing as well ...)

Comment: It's a matter of overhead, as you mentioned, and it seems like I should be able to test the code easily on my own machine before involving any repos.

Comment: This is the main reason I prefer submodules over Nuget packages for internal libraries. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817315/732673

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create your own Nuget feed (simple local folder + some configurations)

Read more here [Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Comment: Is there a way to switch to the local-folder package source other than uninstalling from the old one and then reinstalling? That's not so straightforward, as in the solution I'm working on there are 20 projects, only 5 of which use the library. It's not insurmountable, but annoying.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this? Our team is working on multiple projects, and have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps. It'd be great to locally develop and consume those libs, and then have the DevOps build agent consume a build artifact from our Nuget feed.

Answer (score 29):

I found the following workaround useful for me:

First I disable "NuGet Package Restore" from the context menu of the Solution.

After that I go to the `%HOMEPATH%\.nuget\packages` folder, and search for the package I want to replace. From this package I take the version number, and use this exact version number to build the dll I want to exchange.

After that I can exchange the dll in the packages folder with this newly built dll. Building the project now uses this new dll.

After having this set up once, I can easily build new dlls, and copy them to the packages folder.

Comment: disable "NuGet Package Restore" is not necessary

Comment: I get an error when I try this - "Assembly {assembly path} must be strong signed in order to be marked as a prerequisite."

Comment: could you elaborate on how you "use this exact version number to build the dll I want to exchange."

Answer (score 15):

In VS2019, this is how you can conditionally switch on build between project reference and package reference. We use this for our docker containers

1. Open your project solution "Solutions\Bookstore\Bookstore.sln" that has the project "Bookstore.csproj" that will reference the nuget
2. Add a solution folder for example "nuget" and add existing project "Solutions\Library\library.csproj"
3. Add conditional item group to the project file "Bookstore.csproj"

   ```
   <ItemGroup Condition="Exists('..\..\Library\library.csproj')">
     <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Library\library.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup Condition="!Exists('..\..\Library\library.csproj')">
     <PackageReference Include="library" Version="1.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
4. In solution explorer, right click Bookstore solution > properties > configuration properties. For the configuration 'Release' uncheck the project 'library.csproj'. Now when your code is built in debug, it will build the project reference. When it is built in release it won't try to build it.
5. When we publish make sure you use 'Release'. This works because when you publish it will not be able to find "Solutions\Library\library.csproj" from the path we configured in Bookstore.csproj "..\..\Library\library.csproj".
6. You don't have to use docker for this to work but as an example here
   is the commands our dockerfile will run

   ```
   WORKDIR "/Solutions/Bookstore"
   RUN dotnet restore
   RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app
   FROM build AS publish
   RUN dotnet publish "Bookstore.csproj" -c Release -o /app
   FROM base AS final
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=publish /app .
   ```

Answer (score 10):

We've had great success using this tool. It's easy to use and works.

VS 2019
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2019

VS 2017
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2017

VS 2015
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2015

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seems to support newer project files.

Comment: I added the VS 2019 link. It may help @AJHenderson (not tested).

Comment: @Kit: it seems not, unfortunately. With VS 2019 and the provided extension version, I get an error popup with a stack trace and hint to unload projects with new `.csproj` format.

Answer (score 6):

DNT (DotNetTools) is pretty up to date and has commands to switch from packages to local project references and back again.

`dnt switch-to-projects`

`dnt switch to packages`

https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT#switch-to-projects

Answer (score 6):

In `.csproj` project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
  <ProjectReference Include="../../../Library1/Library1.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="../../../Library2/Library2.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='Debug'">
  <PackageReference Include="Library1" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Library2" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**In development**: project compiled in debug mode, so the project reference  will be used.

**In production** (CI server, docker container): project compiled in release mode, so the package reference will be used.